# sqlite update with subquery omits ".0" in texts

Tags: sqlite

I need to update a text column in `products` from a text column in `properties` where the keys line up. `products` has a many-to-one relation with `properties`, eg: multiple rows in products can link to one property.

```
UPDATE products SET products._num_assist = (SELECT number FROM properties WHERE products.key = properties.key)
```

Example of what is in (TEXT) `properties.number`: "0.0", "1.2", "5.5"...

What now happens is, anywhere properties.number ends with ".0", it's not copied. So what is copied: "0", "1.2", "5.5".

What is going on?

I'm using [DB Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) to run the queries.

Comment: Post the definitions of the tables with sample data to clarify your problem.

Comment: I fixed it by moving the column up a few positions. Perhaps there is a bug in DB browser or something. I dont know, query runs fine now.